# Bindings from Multiple ViewModels in same View WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datacontext

I have a WPF MVVM project that includes a *View* which contains several controls.

There is a **DockPanel** which contains all the controls in the *View* with DataContext to a *MainViewModel* Class, and inside of it there is a *Grid* with DataContext to other object *ViewModel* which it's property contained in the *MainViewModel* Class.

Now, in that ***Grid*** I have a **2 buttons** surrounds with **WrapPanel**, and the buttons have a Commands to a property which wrote in the *MainViewModel* Class, and when I pressed on it nothing happens (Because the *Grid's* DataContext is to other object).

I need the Commands to be stay in the *MainViewModel* Class, How can I do that?

**XAML:** (just the relevant parts)

```
<DockPanel x:Name="MonitorParent" DataContext="{Binding MonitorMainViewModel}" LastChildFill="False" Width="1144" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
      .......     
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentControl Visibility="{Binding Path=NoMonitorsMessageVisibility, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">
            <StackPanel Width="804" Height="574">
                <Grid DataContext="{Binding CurrentMonitor}" Margin="10 0" Height="auto">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="23" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="23" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="23" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="140" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="15"  Content="Serial Number" x:Name="SerialNumber"   />
                    <WrapPanel  DataContext="{Binding MonitorMainViewModel}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="6" >
                        <Button Content="Add" Width="60" Margin="0,0,40,0" Command="{Binding AddConfidenceCommand}" />
                        <Button Content="Delete" Width="60" Margin="30,0,0,0" Command="{Binding DeleteConfidenceCommand}"/>
                    </WrapPanel>

                     ........
  </DockPanel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the name of the `DockPanel` for binding like this:

```
<DockPanel x:Name="MonitorParent" DataContext="{Binding MonitorMainViewModel}" LastChildFill="False" Width="1144" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
  .......     
<StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Visibility="{Binding Path=NoMonitorsMessageVisibility, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">
        <StackPanel Width="804" Height="574">
            <Grid DataContext="{Binding CurrentMonitor}" Margin="10 0" Height="auto">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="23" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="23" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="23" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="140" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="15"  Content="Serial Number" x:Name="SerialNumber"   />
                <WrapPanel  DataContext="{Binding MonitorMainViewModel}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="6" >
                    <Button Content="Add" Width="60" Margin="0,0,40,0" Command="{Binding ElementName=MonitorParent, Path=DataContext.AddConfidenceCommand}" />
                    <Button Content="Delete" Width="60" Margin="30,0,0,0" Command="{Binding ElementName=MonitorParent, Path=DataContext.DeleteConfidenceCommand}"/>
                </WrapPanel>

                 ........
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Button Content="Add" Width="60" Margin="0,0,40,0" 
        Command="{Binding DataContext.AddConfidenceCommand, ElementName=MonitorParent}" />
```

Or:

```
<Button Content="Add" Width="60" Margin="0,0,40,0" 
        Command="{Binding DataContext.AddConfidenceCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DockPanel}}" />
```

Comment: I answered first :)